# How do I make a video a background in html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I want to make a site with a video background in html/css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.videoBackground {
background: url('videobackgroundtech.mp4');
width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
z-index: 1;
opacity: 0.9;
backdrop-filter: blur(13px);
height: 100%;
}
</style>
<body class="videoBackground">
<div class="background1">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And nothing shows, how can I make a video background in HTML/CSS?

The CSS includes the video background so do I just need JavaScript?

Comment: just layer things with z-index.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thank you